# How to install the latest java 11 java-11-openjdk-devel-11.0.21.0.9-1.fc37.x86_64.rpm

Tags: linux, docker, fedora

I have a fedora:37 docker image. I am trying to install java 11.0.21.
Initially i tried `dnf -y install` java-11-openjdk` . this install 11.0.20

How to i get 11.0.21 install ?

I have tried

```
RUN set -ex; \
    wget -nv -O /tmp/java-11-openjdk-devel.rpm "https://rpmfind.net/linux/fedora/linux/updates/testing/37/Everything/x86_64/Packages/j/java-11-openjdk-devel-11.0.21.0.9-1.fc37.x86_64.rpm"; \
    dnf install -y /tmp/java-11-openjdk-devel.rpm
```

i get

```
Error:
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides java-11-openjdk(x86-64) = 1:11.0.21.0.9-1.fc37 needed by java-11-openjdk-devel-1:11.0.21.0.9-1.fc37.x86_64 from @commandline
```

Comment: Why not use a dedicated java base image, e.g. [eclipse-temurin (`hub.docker.com`)](https://hub.docker.com/_/eclipse-temurin)?

Comment: That image has some vulnerabilities from wiz scan and checkmarx